# Heroku Connection Error

Tags: heroku

I have a separate Backbone client and a server that it needs to connect to. I'm using socket.io and this is my server config as of now:

```
var IOServer = require('socket.io')
var port = (process.env.PORT || 9720),
io = new IOServer(port);
```

From what I've read, heroku assigns you a random port number. But I think it should work if I just put the link

```
var socket = io.connect('https://thawing-tundra-87100.herokuapp.com');
```

When I go to the server link above, I get

**This thawing-tundra-87100.herokuapp.com page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: https://thawing-tundra-87100.herokuapp.com/
HTTP ERROR 404**

But checking the logs, it's running correctly I believe.

So the server is on heroku and I am trying to connect to the server using my localhost instance of the client. However, the client is getting a connection refused

**https://thawing-tundra-87100.herokuapp.com:5000/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1482456831163-0 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

Is there something else I need to do or am I missing something?